# zapier bullhorn trigger for updated candidate record

Tags: rest, api, zapier, hubspot

How do I create a trigger in zapier that would trigger when a candidate record is updated/created in bullhorn ATS? The polling webhook in zapier only supports **basic authentication**, but bullhorn uses **OAuth 2.0**. What would the zap look like with these limitations in mind?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I see that we [support](https://zapier.com/apps/bullhorn-crm/integrations) Bullhorn CRM and there's a trigger for new candidate. The easiest thing for you is probably to write into `contact@zapier.com` and ask that we get an "updated candidate" trigger added.

Separately, if you do want to make a webhook trigger manually, you'll need to get an auth token manually. I'm not familiar with Bullhorn's auth specifically, but usually for OAuth2 this involves the following:

1. Create an "app" on the site
2. Manually go through the auth flow w/ Postman or curl and get a token
3. Include that token (either in the header or as a query param, whatever the docs say) with requests

If you're lucky, there's a "generate testing token" on the app page that will give you a token that just works.